# JPQL: order by count(i > ?) is not allowed

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I am trying to form a JPQL Query which is ordered by count of some of the features. Let's assume entity Basket:

```
Basket - (Long) id, (String) name, (Set<Thing>) things_in_basket
```

I am trying to write a query to be ordered by some of the inner features. I would like to achieve something like:

```
SELECT b FROM Basket b ORDER BY COUNT(things_in_basket.id > 1000) DESC
```

But it is obviously not working - it says: `expecting CLOSE, found '>'` - is it even possible with JPQL? In classic SQL it would not be difficult.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are using your `ORDER BY` clause to both order and filter the results. That's not correct. The `ORDER BY` clause should only be used to order the results. If you want to filter them then add a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT b 
FROM Basket b 
ORDER BY COUNT(things_in_basket.id) DESC
WHERE things_in_basket.id > 1000
```

Comment: Why it is not correct? In MySQL it is well defined. In my case even values with less then 1000 will be shown, in your case, they will be discarded.